# How to remove namespace from an XML Element using C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have an XML where I have a name space `_spreadSheetNameSapce`. In my code I have to add a new element with attribute associated with the name the space and I am doing it like the following

```
XElement customHeading = new XElement("Row",
    new XAttribute(_spreadSheetNameSapce + "AutoFitHeight", "0"));
```

It creates the `XElement` properly but it does insert `xmlns=""` entry also in the same element. I do not want that element to be created. How can I create the `XElement` without the empty name space or how can I remove the namespace after the element is created?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all namespaces from XML with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c)

Comment: Found the problem, the code should be
new XElement(_SpreadSheetNameSpace + "Row" ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is currently creating an element *without* a namespace. Presumably this is within an element which *is* in a namespace, which is why it's adding the `xmlns=""` part. If you just want it to keep within the same namespace, just use:

```
XElement customHeading = new XElement(_spreadSheetNameSapce + "Row",
        new XAttribute(_spreadSheetNameSapce + "AutoFitHeight", "0"));
```

Just to stress again, this isn't about *removing* a namespace - it's about putting an element into the same namespace as the "default" inherited from its parent.