# How to convert XML via XSLT and ignore 2 XMLNS

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<Products xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">

<Product>
<status>1</status> 
<ProductName>******************</ProductName> 
<model>******************</model>
<ProductQTY>******************</ProductQTY> 
<CostPrice>******************</CostPrice>
<RetailPrice>******************</RetailPrice> 
<FullCategoryPath>******************</FullCategoryPath>
<description> 
<![CDATA[******************
]]></description> 
<image_link>https://******************</image_link> 
</Product>
<Product>
<status>1</status>
<ProductName>******************</ProductName>
<model>******************7</model>
<ProductQTY>0</ProductQTY> 
<CostPrice>1******************</CostPrice>
<RetailPrice>141.9</RetailPrice> 
<FullCategoryPath>******************</FullCategoryPath><description> 
<![CDATA******************
  ]]></description> 
<image_link>https://******************</image_link>
</Product>
</Products>    <!-- Added by edit -->
```

as you see above.
How can I fix my XSLT file?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
            xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
            xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"               
            exclude-result-prefixes="sitemap image">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() "/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xml>
            <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                <xsl:choose >
                    <xsl:when test="node() | model !=''">
                        <Product>     
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() "/>
                            <SProductCode >
                                <xsl:value-of select="node() | @model" />
                            </SProductCode>
                            <CategoryName>
                                <value-of select=""/>
                            </CategoryName>
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                        </Product>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xml>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>    <!-- Added by edit -->
```

For example:
How can I show category names product name ex. from my node(). I can't parse them.

> xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
>   xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"

These two namespaces ruin me so badly.They are inside of my root element"Products".

Output is:  All values are false .

```
<xml>
     <Product>
       <SProductCode>1</SProductCode>
       <CategoryName>
         <value-of select="node() | @model" />
       </CategoryName>
     </Product>
     <Product>
       <SProductCode>1</SProductCode>
       <CategoryName>
         <value-of select="node() | @model" />
       </CategoryName>
     </Product>
```

What am I gonna write for "SProductCode" or"CategoryName" to properly run it?

Comment: In the result do appear only `SProductCode>` and `CategoryName` elements with values beside empty `<xml/>` nodes. Is it possible that you gave a partial output as input XML in your question?

Comment: The namespaces listed in the XML are not actually used anywhere (all the elements in your XML are not in any namespaces) so they shouldn't actually cause a problem in this instance.

Comment: @zx485          Output added

Comment: @timc if ı write a normal xslt , Im getting null xml because sitemap and image block to list it .

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Is this the desired output? When I apply the stylesheet, I get a different output. And in what way is that problem related to the namespaces, because, as @TimC wrote, they are unused in the XML?

Comment: @zx485   My output should be like <SProductCode> filled </SProductCode>,<CategoryName> filled <CategoryName>,and other Properties filled with data from my received XML source.As you show First Product xml ,xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" These 2 xmlns unfortunately prevent my output.Thanks for your struggles.

Comment: If you're just removing namespaces, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268182/how-to-remove-namespaces-from-xml-using-xslt

Answer (score 0):

The following modified template approaches your desired output. I removed some unnecessary code, but I couldn't derive which values you want to put into the `xsl:value-of select="..." />`. I also changed your `xsl:choose` to a simple predicate of the `Product` `xsl:for-each` loop.

```
<xsl:template match="/Products">
    <xml>
        <xsl:for-each select="Product[model != '']">
            <Product>     
                <SProductCode >
                    <xsl:value-of select="model" />
                </SProductCode>
                <CategoryName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="FullCategoryPath"/>
                </CategoryName>
                .
                .
                .
                .
            </Product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xml>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<xml>
    <Product>
        <SProductCode>******************</SProductCode>
        <CategoryName>******************</CategoryName>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <SProductCode>******************7</SProductCode>
        <CategoryName>******************</CategoryName>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </Product>
</xml>
```

Comment: ı put breakpoint to check then it's not enter the <xsl:template match="/Products">. So they are not getting my Product attributes like SProductCode,CategoryName...

Comment: Of course you can (and must) adjust the `match` rule to the actual  design of your full XML. It could be simply `Products` instead, for example.

Comment: I tried almost all posibilities and again null.I can't take right values from xml and parse them in my xml attributes.