# XmlDocument Remove XMLNS from Root Element

Tags: c#, xmldocument, createelement

New here, looking to get a little help with my XmlDocument. Is it possible to have string data in my root element AND remove the ***xmlns=*** attribute from being shown? I'm looking for something like this:

```
<Rulebase author=yadda datetime=bingbang version=1.x </Rulebase>
```

When I try to use my string data by doing:

```
xmlDom.AppendChild(xmlDom.CreateElement("", "Rulebase", data));
XmlElement xmlRoot = xmlDom.DocumentElement;
```

It ends up looking like this:

```
<Rulebase xmlns="version=0 author=username date=7/13/2011 </Rulebase>
```

and it also appends ***xmlns=""*** to all my other nodes.

Comment: I hope this is useful to you...[How to remove all namespaces from XML with C#?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c

Comment: Please post the actual XML. What you posted is not XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CreateElement` overload you're using takes a prefix as it's first argument, local name as second, and namespace as third.  If you don't want a namespace, don't use this overload.  Just use the one that takes a local name as the one and only argument.  Then add your data separately as child elements and attributes.

```
var xmlDom = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = xmlDom.CreateElement("Rulebase");
xmlDom.AppendChild(root);
XmlElement data = xmlDom.CreateElement("Data");
root.AppendChild(data);

XmlAttribute attribute = xmlDom.CreateAttribute("author");
attribute.Value = "username";
data.Attributes.Append(attribute);

attribute = xmlDom.CreateAttribute("date");
attribute.Value = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);
data.Attributes.Append(attribute);

Console.WriteLine(xmlDom.OuterXml);
```

Creates (formatting added)

```
<Rulebase>
    <Data author="username" date="2011-07-13T22:44:27.5488853-04:00" />
</Rulebase>
```

Using `XmlDocument` to generate XML is pretty tedious though.  There are many better ways in .NET, like `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer`.  You can also use Linq-to-Xml and `XElement`.  Or you can use an `XmlWriter.Create()`.  Lots of options.

Comment: -1 for mentioning `XmlTextWriter`, deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Comment: @John Saunders, technically, it's not deprecated, but I updated my answer to point to `XmlWriter` instead.

Comment: perhaps you mean that it isn't marked with `[Obsolete]`, but the fact that they say, "don't use `new XmlTextWriter()`, instead use `XmlWriter.Create()`" is the same IMO as "`new XmlTextWriter()` is deprecated in favor of `XmlWriter.Create()`"

Comment: @John Saunders, yes, that's why I updated my answer.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: many thanks, i ended up doing it the way you provided in the example. a little tedious but not a big deal. really appreciate all the responses!