# Can we pass xml formatted text to inner xml?

Tags: asp.net, xml

I want to pass xml formatted text to inner xml text. Is it possible?

```
 XmlNode parentNode = myTemplate.CreateNode (XmlNodeType.Element, "Parent","myns");
 XmlNode childNode = myTemplate.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "head", "myns");
 childNode.InnerText = "<paragraph>sample text</paragraph>";
 parentNode.AppendChild(childNode);
```

but my O/P is coming like

```
<head>&lt;paragraph&gt;sample text&lt;/paragraph&gt;</head>
```

desired O/P is

```
<head><paragraph>sample text</paragraph></head>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you writer something to InnerText it is HTMLEncoded, this is required otherwise xml parser cannot identify difference between main xml and inner text.

it looks like you want to add inner xml instead of text , for this try childNode.InnerXML instead of childNode.InnerText.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `InnerText` that will remove the markup. User `innerXml` instead.

```
childNode.InnerXml = "<paragraph>sample text</paragraph>";
```

Comment: When I try to add InnerXml it is showing <paragraph xmlns="">sample text</paragraph>. I dont want xmlns="" to be added. Hope you understand

Comment: Yes I got it. [Here is a good example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c) of how to remove namespaces from xml.