# Remove element namespace prefixes from XML string fragment

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xml, xml-parsing

I have a string containing a partial XML fragment, which may contain various undeclared namespaces and therefore cannot be parsed by the XML parser I'm using (.Net's `XElement.Parse`):

```
<elements>
    <removeThis:element attribute="value">
        Contents
    </removeThis:element>
</elements>
```

So before passing the string to the XML parser I need to strip the namespaces from the string (I don't need the namespaces, I just need the fragment to parse):

```
<elements>
    <element attribute="value">
        Contents
    </element>
</elements>
```

Any suggestions on ways to achieve this result, e.g. a Regular Expression, or some option I'm not ware of within .Net's XML parser?

Comment: Is this something that you are looking for ?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305747/how-to-remove-xmlns-attribute-of-a-node-other-than-root-in-an-xdocument

Comment: No sadly that answer does not help with removing the namespace prefix from the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method with regular expressions. This workes if xml did not contain `CData` and replaces only element names (not attributes).

```
// read xml string
string input = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Temp\text.txt");

// replace
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(<\s*\/?)\s*(\w+):(\w+)", "$1$3");
```

Comment: Nice, thank you, seems to work well after a quick initial test

Answer (score 0):

Sample xml:

```
<elements xmlns:removeThis="xmlnsname">
    <removeThis:element attribute="value">
        Contents
    </removeThis:element>
</elements>
```

Code:

```
private static void RemoveNamespaces(XElement element)
{
    // remove namespace prefix
    element.Name = element.Name.LocalName;

    // remove namespaces from children elements
    foreach (var elem in element.Elements())
    {
        RemoveNamespaces(elem);
    }

    // remove namespace attributes
    foreach (var attr in element.Attributes())
    {
        if (attr.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
        {
            attr.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (I save sample xml in file 'D:\Temp\temp.txt'):

```
var elem = XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Temp\text.txt"));
RemoveNamespaces(elem);
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"D:\Temp\text.txt", new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    }))
{
    elem.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Result:

```
<elements>
  <element attribute="value">
        Contents
    </element>
</elements>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the input is a string that cannot be parsed using `XElement.Parse(string)` as the missing namespace declarations cause this error: "Could not parse input to valid XDocument"