# XDocument xmlns url attributes persist to child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Based on [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305747/how-to-remove-xmlns-attribute-of-a-node-other-than-root-in-an-xdocument?msclkid=56922e00d0d111ec9074924a9f78cfa3#:%7E:text=Adding%20the%20same%20namespace%20to%20your%20childs%20as%20well%20will%20solve), adding the same namespace to your child node will prevent creating empty `xmlns=""` attributes. I'm not getting empty attributes, instead it duplicates the same xmlns in root to child node.

My current output:

```xml
<Root xmlns="http://my.namespace">     
     <FirstElement xmlns="http://my.namespace"/> 
</Root>
```

Expected output:

```xml
<Root xmlns="http://my.namespace">     
     <FirstElement/> 
</Root>
```

Sharing my code:

```cs
        private XDocument CreateRootTag()
        {
            XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://my.namespace");
            var xdec = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
            XDocument xml = new XDocument(
                    xdec,
                    new XElement(
                        xmlns + "Root",
                        new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                        CreateFirstElementTag()));  // <--- adding child node containing duplicate xmlns as root

            return xml;
        }



        private XElement CreateFirstElementTag()
        {
            XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://my.namespace");
            XElement firstElementTag = new XElement(xmlns + "FirstElement","hello");
            return firstElementTag;
        }
```

How to prevent persisting `xmlns="my.namespace"` attributes in child node?

Please let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code as follows. And didn't encounter any issues.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = CreateRootTag();
    Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
}

private XDocument CreateRootTag()
{
    XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://my.namespace");
    var xdec = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
    XDocument xml = new XDocument(
            xdec,
            new XElement(
                xmlns + "Root",
                new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                CreateFirstElementTag()));  // <--- adding child node containing duplicate xmlns as root

    return xml;
}

private XElement CreateFirstElementTag()
{
    XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://my.namespace");
    XElement firstElementTag = new XElement(xmlns + "FirstElement", "hello");
    return firstElementTag;
}
```

**Output**

```
<Root version="1.0" xmlns="http://my.namespace">
  <FirstElement>hello</FirstElement>
</Root>
```