# Remove attributes from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Please consider this XElement:

```
<MySerializeClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <F1>1</F1>
    <F2>2</F2>
    <F3>nima</F3>
</MySerializeClass>
```

I want to delete `xmlns:xsi` and `xmlns:xsd` from above XML.
I wrote this code but it does not work:

```
 XAttribute attr = xml.Attribute("xmlns:xsi");
 attr.Remove();
```

I got this error:

> Additional information: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

How I can delete above attributes?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `xml.Attributes().Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove()`. Or use `xml.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi").Remove()`.

Answer (score 2):

you  can try the following

```
//here I suppose that I'm loading your Xelement from a file :)
 var xml = XElement.Load("tst.xml"); 
 xml.RemoveAttributes();
```

from  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Xml.Linq.XElement.RemoveAttributes%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) 
*`Removes the attributes of this XElement`*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use namespaces, LINQ to XML makes that really easy:

```
xml.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi").Remove();
```

here final clean and universal C# solution for removing all XML namespaces:

```
public static string RemoveAllNamespaces(string xmlDocument)
{
    XElement xmlDocumentWithoutNs = RemoveAllNamespaces(XDocument.Load(xmlDocument).Root);

    return xmlDocumentWithoutNs.ToString();
}

//Core recursion function
 private static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement xmlDocument)
    {
        if (!xmlDocument.HasElements)
        {
            XElement xElement = new XElement(xmlDocument.Name.LocalName);
            xElement.Value = xmlDocument.Value;

            foreach (XAttribute attribute in xmlDocument.Attributes())
                xElement.Add(attribute);

            return xElement;
        }
        return new XElement(xmlDocument.Name.LocalName, xmlDocument.Elements().Select(el => RemoveAllNamespaces(el)));
    }
```

> Output

```
 <MySerializeClass>
  <F1>1</F1> 
  <F2>2</F2> 
  <F3>nima</F3> 
 </MySerializeClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner way.

1. Declare an extension method :

   ```
    public static void RemoveXmlAttributes(this XElement xDocument)
    {
        xDocument.RemoveAttributes();
        foreach (XElement xmlChild in xDocument.Elements())
        {
            xmlChild.RemoveXmlAttributes();
        }
    }
   ```
2. Then call it :

   ```
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(completionXml);
        xml.RemoveXmlAttributes();
   ```

The same can be done for XmlElement (instead of XElement)