# remove text where regex pattern has trailing backslash doublequote at end of string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string from which I need to remove some characters that end in backslash doublequote.  There are multiple matches.  I have it to where it ALMOST works, except I can't get rid of the last backslash double quote (\") in each place that the namespace occurs.

I went to regexpal.com and came up with this regex string that does what I want.

```
xmlns=*.+be/\\"
```

But when I put it in C# the two backslashes make it grab way too much.  This code repeats my issue and shows my progress:

```
var str = "<Request>  <sender xmlns=\"http://stuff.otherstuff.be/\">    <name>Sender name</name>    </sender>  <addressee xmlns=\"http://some.stuff.be/\"> </addressee>  <networkType xmlns=\"http://yet.more.stuff.be/\">11</networkType></Request>";

str = Regex.Replace(str, @"xmlns=.*?\.be/", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I wind up with a string that looks like this.  I need to modify the regex a bit to also catch the backslash and double quote

```
<Request>  
    <sender \">    
         <name>Sender name</name>    
    </sender>  
    <addressee \"> 
    </addressee>  
    <networkType \">11</networkType>
</Request>
```

I've tried various combinations of multiple backslashes and multiple double quotes but am not getting it.

I have looked at a lot of answers here and elsewhere, and haven't figured it out, so a "has duplicate" isn't really going to help me.

EDIT: At this point in the code all I have is a string that came from a serialized class.  I don't really want to load the string into and XMLDocument and do recursive calls like in the possible answer shown.  A quick regex replace should get me what I need in 1 statement.

EDIT:  The answer with adding two doublequotes does not help me because it ignores the final backslash that I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: You `str` looks like `<Request>  <sender xmlns="http://stuff.otherstuff.be/">    <name>Sender name</name>    </sender>  <addressee xmlns="http://some.stuff.be/"> </addressee>  <networkType xmlns="http://yet.more.stuff.be/">11</networkType></Request>`. There are no ``\"`` literal strings inside. Is that your input?

Comment: my bad.  The backslash should be in .be/\"

Comment: Try `str2 = Regex.Replace(str2, @"\s*xmlns=.*?\.be/""", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`. However, I guess there are better ways to remove XML namespaces.

Comment: actually, no - it is correct.  The backslash doublequote .be/\" is there in the string 3 times.  I see it here in my question and in my code when I run.  Not sure why it doesn't show for what you posted

Comment: This is coming from a xml serialized class that I don't have control over.  If there is a better way, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: Isn't [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c) helpful? If you decide that yes, and decide to use any of the solutions discussed there, just remove this question.

Comment: No, the post isn't helpful, but thank you.

Comment: Not fixed.  Still there.  Not sure why I got downvoted.  It's a real issue and I'm being as clear as I can.  It needs to be a string replace and it ends in a backslash doublequote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90023/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-brad-boyce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that to remove XML namespaces, you can use regular C# code described at [*How to remove all namespaces from XML with C#?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c), but since you say that does not help, here is a solution for your special case.

In order to remove any slashes you may use a character class `[/\\]` - just in case you have both `\` and `/`. Note that a literal backslash must be doubled in a verbatim string literal.

The regex will look like

```
\s*xmlns=[^<]*?\.be[/\\]"
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*xmlns%3d%5b%5e%3c%5d*%3f%5c.be%5b%2f%5c%5c%5d%22&i=xmlns%3d%5c%22stuff.otherstuff.be%5c%22&o=i)

And in C#:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\s*xmlns=[^<]*?\.be[/\\]""");
```

The `\s*` will "trim" the whitespace in the resulted replacement.

[Results after replacing with `string.Empty`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*xmlns%3D%5B%5E%3C%5D*%3F%5C.be%5B%2F%5C%5C%5D%22&i=%3CRequest%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Csender%20xmlns%3D%5C%22stuff.otherstuff.be%5C%22%3E%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3ESender%20name%3C%2Fname%3E%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsender%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Caddressee%20xmlns%3D%5C%22stuff.otherstuff.be%5C%22%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Faddressee%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CnetworkType%20xmlns%3D%5C%22stuff.otherstuff.be%5C%22%3E11%3C%2FnetworkType%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FRequest%3E&r=&o=i):

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Works just like I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the trailing quote like this (if using the `@` syntax you must use `""` to match a one quote):

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"xmlns=.*?\.be/""", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Add a space at the beginning if you want `<sender>` instead of `<sender >`:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @" xmlns=.*?\.be/""", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I really do need to match a backslash before the final doublequote.  I need to match this in multiple places 

xmlns=\"http://stuff.otherstuff.be/\"

Comment: i don't understand it   the slashes are being wiped out.  the string to be matched should end in [period lowercase b lowercase e forwardslash backslash doublequote]

Comment: @mathew strawbridge , can you show me a regex string that will match a set of characters that ends in  forwardslash, backslash, doublequote?