# Soap Xml Node Prefix

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, xmlnode

I want to write a basic test tool that will build some soap request by merging the headers and body of xml, and than checks the result. But when I inspect the xml request examples of soap I see that xml
nodes have a prefix like "soapenv" or "s" ..

For example:

```
<soapenv:Header>
```

or

```
<s:Header>
```

1) Is there a way to reject prefix and select node with only key "Header" ? And than insert a string xml to header ?

2) What is the reason of this prefix ? Why it changes ?

Comment: 1. Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/988325/4684493) help? 2. [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122002/why-do-we-need-uris-for-xml-namespaces) may help to explain.

Comment: use xml linq :             XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("your xml string");
            XElement header = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Header").FirstOrDefault();