# How to remove schema reference in each elements from the xml using C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I'm having the xml in below format, which is having xml namespaces references for each nodes.

```
<Root xmlns:sch1="URL1" xmlns:sch2="URL2">
    <sch1:ProductDetails>
        <sch1:Product>
            <sch1:ProductId>1</sch1:ProductId>
            <sch1:ProductName>ProductOne</sch1:ProductName>
        </sch1:Product>
        <sch1:Product>
            <sch1:ProductId>2</sch1:ProductId>
            <sch1:ProductName>ProductTwo</sch1:ProductName>
        </sch1:Product>
    </sch1:ProductDetails>
    <sch2:EmployeeDetails>
        <sch2:Employee>
            <sch2:EmployeeId>1</sch2:EmployeeId>
            <sch2:EmployeeName>NameOne</sch2:EmployeeName>
        </sch2:Employee>
        <sch2:Employee>
            <sch2:EmployeeId>2</sch2:EmployeeId>
            <sch2:EmployeeName>NameTwo</sch2:EmployeeName>
        </sch2:Employee>
    </sch2:EmployeeDetails>
</Root>
```

and my expected output xml should be as,

```
<Root>
    <ProductDetails>
        <Product>
            <ProductId>1</ProductId>
            <ProductName>ProductOne</ProductName>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProductId>2</ProductId>
            <ProductName>ProductTwo</ProductName>
        </Product>
    </ProductDetails>
    <EmployeeDetails>
        <Employee>
            <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
            <EmployeeName>NameOne</EmployeeName>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
            <EmployeeName>NameTwo</EmployeeName>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeDetails>
</Root>
```

How to get this output in C# using XmlDocument or XDocument. Please suggest.

Comment: please review this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c