# Linq to Xml : Remove namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am retrieving an element or node from my xml doc. All goes well but when I retrieve the node it gets assigned the namespace of my root. This I don't want. I just want the node as it was before (without namespace).

My element that is retrieve is e.g. xElement.
I am tried

1. `xElement.Attributes("xmlns").Remove();`
2. `xElement.Attributes("xmlns").Where(x=>x.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();`

None of them did the trick.

I even tried this example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e6f77ad-9a7b-46c5-97ed-6ce9b5954e79/how-do-i-remove-a-namespace-from-an-xelement?forum=xmlandnetfx This left met with an element with an empty namespace `xmlns=""`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988325/2118383)

> Based on interface:
>
> ```
> string RemoveAllNamespaces(string xmlDocument);
> ```
>
> I represent here final clean and universal C# solution for removing
>   XML namespaces:
>
> ```
> //Implemented based on interface, not part of algorithm
> public static string RemoveAllNamespaces(string xmlDocument)
> {
>     XElement xmlDocumentWithoutNs = RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement.Parse(xmlDocument));
>
>     return xmlDocumentWithoutNs.ToString();
> }
>
> //Core recursion function
>  private static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement xmlDocument)
>     {
>         if (!xmlDocument.HasElements)
>         {
>             XElement xElement = new XElement(xmlDocument.Name.LocalName);
>             xElement.Value = xmlDocument.Value;
>
>             foreach (XAttribute attribute in xmlDocument.Attributes())
>                 xElement.Add(attribute);
>
>             return xElement;
>         }
>         return new XElement(xmlDocument.Name.LocalName, xmlDocument.Elements().Select(el => RemoveAllNamespaces(el)));
>     }
> ```

Above solution still have two flase

- It ignores attributes
- It doesn't work with "mixed mode" elements

Here is another solution:

```cs
 public static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement e)
 {
    return new XElement(e.Name.LocalName,
      (from n in e.Nodes()
        select ((n is XElement) ? RemoveAllNamespaces(n as XElement) : n)),
          (e.HasAttributes) ? 
            (from a in e.Attributes() 
               where (!a.IsNamespaceDeclaration)  
               select new XAttribute(a.Name.LocalName, a.Value)) : null);
  }
```

Sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/dalegaspi/9ef8a241339c1de62413#file-removexmlnamespace-cs).